Need help finding out the brand
Hi everyone need help identifying the brand this logo represents. Did extensive search with Google and Global Brand Database came up empty and hope someone here recognizes this brand.
This logo is on a MTB at least 9 years old.


Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Some pictures of the bike itself might help get a better idea of the year, which could in turn help figure this out.

Hi David, I was pinning my hopes on the logo and did not want to ad pictures of the bike upfront as it has been fittet with battery cells from bikee, at first thought and first i believed the bike to be from them. The logo stood in contrast to the other indicators I will follow up with pictures of the bike and be happy to hear any thoughts on the bike. cheers Doris

Strange that you didn't get an answer from Google; this is the MBK/Motobecane logo.
https://mbkbikes.com/

Paul thank you so much yes been hours on the screen looking for this logo, possible i could have refined search values, but at last i have a name for the logo thanks to you. Much appreciate your help!

Excellent find!   A google image search for "mbk motobecane logo" shows so many different variations, its not surprising OP didn't find it.   Welcome to the site !
